# How to process a response from the Twilio REST API

Tags: python, twilio

I am developing a program to help treat depression. I do not have a deep understanding of Twilio. I would like to collect the responses to this message:

```
Sent from your Twilio trial account - What are the positive results or outcomes you have achieved lately?
What are the strengths and resources you have available to you to get even more results and were likely the reason you got the results in the first question.
What are your current priorities? What do you and your team need to be focused on right now?
What are the benefits to all involved-you
 your team and all other stakeholders who will be impacted by achieving your priority focus.
How can we (you and/or your team) move close? What action steps are needed?
What am I going to do today?
What am I doing tomorrow ?
What did I do yesterday?
```

and process them 1-9. The responses will be enumerated by 1-9.

I've contacted Twilio support and I read these docs https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python.

Here is what I tried:

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
import logging
import csv
import psycopg2
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Set environtment variables
DATABASE = os.environ["DATABASE"]
PASSWORD = os.environ["PASSWORD"]
PORT     = os.environ["PORT"]
USER     = os.environ["USER"]
HOST     = os.environ["HOST"]


# initialization TODO: move into env vars
MY_PHONE_NUMBER        = os.environ["MY_PHONE_NUMBER"]
TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER    = os.environ["TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER"]
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID     = os.environ["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN      = os.environ["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]

# Configure Twillio
# Set environment variables for your credentials
# Read more at http://twil.io/secure
client = Client(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
logging.debug(f"Connected to Twilio using MY_PHONE_NUMBER:{MY_PHONE_NUMBER},TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER{TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER}")

# Establish db connection
# use psycopg to connect to the db and create a table
conn = psycopg2.connect(
database=DATABASE, user=USER, password=PASSWORD, host=HOST, port=PORT)
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()


# Step 1: Set up frequency, i.e. times to send messages

# Step 2: Load questions
questionsFile   = open('questions.csv')
questions = csv.reader(questionsFile)
logging.debug(f"message:{questions}")
message = "\n".join([question for row in questions for question in row])
logging.debug(f"message: {message}")

# Step 3: Send questions
# message = client.messages.create(
#   body=message,
#   from_=TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
#   to=MY_PHONE_NUMBER
# )

# Step 4: Collect response
@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def incoming_sms():
    """Send a dynamic reply to an incoming text message"""
    # Get the message the user sent our Twilio number
    body = request.values.get('Body', None)

    # Start our TwiML response
    resp = MessagingResponse()

    # Determine the right reply for this message
    if body == 'hello':
        resp.message("Hi!")
    elif body == 'bye':
        resp.message("Goodbye")

    return str(resp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

# Step 5: Create a database table as the sheet name and Save responses in db
logging.debug(f'Step 2 creating table response')
# TODO: create 10 columns for saving responses (each response contains 10 answers)
sql = f'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.responses'
logging.debug(f'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.responses')
# cursor.execute(sql)
# conn.commit()

# Next steps:
# 1. Process positive and negative sentiment from responses
# 2. Calculuate total positive sentiment
# 3. Calculate  total negative sentiment
# 4. Plot positive sentiment vs. negative sentiment
```

The documentation doesn't provide a clear path for completing step 4.

[image]
[shows response from text message.]

[image]
[messages url]

Expected
processed responses from the questions.

Actual:

```
Sent from your Twilio trial account - What are the positive results or outcomes you have achieved lately?
What are the strengths and resources you have available to you to get even more results and were likely the reason you got the results in the first question.
What are your current priorities? What do you and your team need to be focused on right now?
What are the benefits to all involved-you
 your team and all other stakeholders who will be impacted by achieving your priority focus.
How can we (you and/or your team) move close? What action steps are needed?
What am I going to do today?
What am I doing tomorrow ?
What did I do yesterday?
```

I added a Twilio flow to test the connection to Twilio. This could go in two directions just python or using a Twilio flow. The flow does not work even after adding the correct number.

[messages screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4PNk.png)

- this comes from the demo video which does not match the current UI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRxirse1UfQ.

Comment: The relevant guidance from the doc url you cited is: "When someone sends a text message to your Twilio number, Twillio can call a webhook you create in Python". Your next step is to create and test a Webhook. It should answer POST requests from public internet web clients, or at least from Twilio's servers. Pay close attention to logging. Also, for good UX, a single SMS prolly wouldn't ask _all_ of those questions at once.

Comment: This is not a "real time" process.  What I mean is, you don't send a message and then wait for a reply.  Instead, you broadcast your messages, then that process is done.  When someone sends a text to you, Twilio will send a web request to the web server you have created.  You have to figure out who it came from and where to put the data.

Comment: Does this help: [reply with flask](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python?code-sample=code-respond-to-an-incoming-text-message)

Comment: Friend, There is never enough time, thank you for yours. Thank you for your integrity. Thank you for your humility. Thank you for your presence. I tried that, but it did not work as expected.

Comment: You tried what?  You surely didn't write a Flask application already.

Comment: I added the sample from the documentation. Then attempted to configure the messaging url.

Comment: May I suggest to read [ask]. From the similar questions you already asked ([Step 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74752681/what-is-the-best-way-to-perform-sentiment-analysis-by-using-text-message-respons), [duplicate Step 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74790288/how-to-process-words-from-a-csv-list)), it seems like we should improve on a [example] here, to save your and our time.

Comment: As Robert Half would say, “Not admitting a mistake is a bigger mistake.” I would like to apologize for any frustration that I caused. This is a different case. Nobody has provided a clear answer for this specific question. I am sure you understand.

Answer (score 0):

There's a second code sample on the [page you linked](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python#code-respond-to-an-incoming-text-message). This explains how you can parse the body of incoming message to read the payload with `request.values.get('Body', None)`:

```py
@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def incoming_sms():
    """Send a dynamic reply to an incoming text message"""
    # Get the message the user sent our Twilio number
    body = request.values.get('Body', None)

    # Start our TwiML response
    resp = MessagingResponse()

    # Determine the right reply for this message
    if body == 'hello':
        resp.message("Hi!")
    elif body == 'bye':
        resp.message("Goodbye")

    return str(resp)
```

However, it makes sense to ask the questions after each other and this means you would need to handle many different endpoint and it can get complicated really fast.

**But there's also a visual editor that allows you to define this within a few minutes in your browser:** [Build a Chatbot with Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-build-a-chatbot)

Comment: Friend, there is never enough time, thank you for yours. Thank you for your integrity. Thank you for your humility. Thank you for your presence. I can't get the flow to work with the phone number the UI is different from the tutorial video.

Comment: You need to use your own phone number which is different from the one in the video

Comment: We’re moving ahead and making progress (on some aspects). I added the twilio registered number in the messaging flow.

Answer (score 0):

```
call = client.calls.create(
                        twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy there!</Say></Response>',
                        to='+15558675310',
                        from_='+15552223214'
                    )

print(call.__dict__)
```